# JPA ManyToOne with repository saving problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my `UserService` I call the `save` method for a new user and the `createdBy` will be set and saved. When the save get called following error occurs:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [at.qe.skeleton.model.User#1];
```

It looks like it tries to save the `User` object (which already exists in the database) which is set at `createdBy`. I tried various CascadeTypes in the ManyToOne annotation but it does not work. Maybe I have some other Annotation wrong, but I don't know what.

I have following classes:
DBEntity.java

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class DBEntity implements Persistable<Long>, Serializable, Comparable<DBEntity> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "default_generator"
    )
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "created_by",
            referencedColumnName = "id",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(
                    name = "created_by_user_id_fk"
            )
    )
    private User createdBy;

    @Column(
            name = "created_on",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE"
    )
    private Date createdOn;
    //shortened 
}
```

User.java

```java
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(
        name = "\"user\"",
        uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(name = "user_username_unique", columnNames = "username")
        }
)
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "default_generator",
        sequenceName = "user_role_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1
)
public class User extends DBEntity {

    @Column(
            name = "username",
            nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String username;
    //shortened 
}
```

UserService.java

```java
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        if (user.isNew()) {
            user.setCreatedOn(new Date());
            user.setCreatedBy(getAuthenticatedUser());
        } else {
            user.setUpdatedOn(new Date());
            user.setUpdatedBy(getAuthenticatedUser());
        }

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    private User getAuthenticatedUser() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return userRepository.findFirstByUsername(auth.getName());
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```java
public interface UserRepository extends AbstractRepository<User, Long> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
The Sequence generator was in conflict with the test data so it tried to give the new user an id which is already in the database